# Clearing TextBox Values after being Cloned using jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, clone

I'm using the following code to clone a row in a table when the user clicks on the Add button:

`$('.addButton').click(function () {
            $('#quotesTable tbody>tr:last').clone(true).insertAfter('#quotesTable tbody>tr:last');
        });`

How can I clear the values of a the new row being added so that they are empty? For example if the user selects a listbox value, and enters text into a text box, then clicks on add, the same exact row is copied with the values selected and entered.

I need the newly added row to be empty.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) method to find all text inputs within the clone and clear their value using the [`val`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) method, passing an empty string as the argument:

```
$('.addButton').click(function () {
    var clone = $('#quotesTable tbody>tr:last').clone(true);
    clone.find("input[type='text'], select").val("");
    clone.insertAfter('#quotesTable tbody>tr:last'); 
});
```

You may want to modify the `input[type='text'], select` selector if you have other controls you wish to clear as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.addButton').click(function () {
    var newRow = $('#quotesTable tbody>tr:last')
        .clone(true)
        .insertAfter('#quotesTable tbody>tr:last');
    newRow.find('.myselect').val(''); // replace with your default value and select class name
    newRow.find('.mytextbox').val(''); // replace with your default value and textbox class name
});
```